# Ficus bonsai regrowth

Tags: pruning, bonsai, ficus

I recently got a ficus bonsai and I've been following instructions to keep it pruned, however, I have a few questions that I can't find information on.

I've allowed a few branches to get a bit longer than they should have and I'm a bit worried about cutting those back. If I cut them back, how will that affect my bonsai? Will the new shoots grow and continue the growth of the branches I cut back, or will that effectively be stopping the branch from growing from that point? Or would it create a point were a new branch will grow from the pruned point?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

When you prune a branch, the branch you cut will not grow longer. It may create new shoots on the branch that you cut or it may not.

People prune branches to create a canopy a the top of their bonsai or they do it to make it shorter because it is too long, or to balance the vigor of a tree. branch pruning for a bonsai is very common and you don't need to be afraid of it. You can check out this YouTube channel [Nigel Saunders, The Bonsai Zone](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxWc7cn-M-22gie8oPslLcA). It has lots of good info and you can see how he prune the branches and why.